Spring Boot + JWT - re-use token in other microservies
My architecture looks like this. I use a gateway to redirect requests to different microservices. I have an auth-service for JWT validation in gateway. In addition to the above there are two services: X and Y. I would like to use the token in services X and Y because, depending on the role, so the user can/cannot perform certain actions. I get the user roles from the token. I wouldn't want to re-validate on sites X and Y just to pull out a role.
Role-based validation looks like this: @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")

I will let someone else answer, maybe there is a more spring-way to do it. But a simple way is to just forward the jwt (or just the payload-part, the part betwern the two dots in the jwt) and let X and Y dig out the scopes them self using base64 decoding. X and Y does not need to check the signature of the jwt again.

Thanks for your comment. The application will run behind a firewall, on the company internal network. i was thinking about deleting rule based security and specify allowed origins in gateway service. Thanks to this solution, role forwarding will not be necessary and I will be sure that no one will try to send requests to an unauthorized endpoint

with gateway, do you mean spring cloud gateway?

Yes, I mean spring cloud gateway
